# Why is my RecyclerView empty even though I'm getting the data from Firestore?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I'm following this short YT video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ly0xwWlUpVM). I followed his code and it works.

But, I'm trying to use a slightly different approach that I saw somewhere else to load the collection from Firestore.

Here's the function that works:

```
private fun EventChangeListener() {
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    db.collection("tournaments")
        .addSnapshotListener(object: EventListener<QuerySnapshot>{
            override fun onEvent(value: QuerySnapshot?, error: FirebaseFirestoreException?) {
                if (error != null) { return }

                Log.i ("BEFORE", tournamentsList.size.toString())
                for (dc: DocumentChange in value?.documentChanges!!) {
                    if (dc.type == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        tournamentsList.add(dc.document.toObject(Tournament::class.java))
                    }
                }
                Log.i ("AFTER ", tournamentsList.size.toString())
                tournamentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

            }
        })
}
```

I'm trying to use this code:

```
private fun EventChangeListener() {
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    db.collection("tournaments").addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error ->
        if (error != null) { return@addSnapshotListener }

        Log.i ("BEFORE", tournamentsList.size.toString())
        tournamentsList = snapshot!!.toObjects(Tournament::class.java) as ArrayList<Tournament>
        Log.i ("AFTER ", tournamentsList.size.toString())

        tournamentAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

I thought these were the same thing, with the second able to read the entire collection in one line, rather than having to loop through the collection one document at a time.

When I add debug statements to the version that uses `toObjects`, I can confirm that `tournamentsList.size` is 0 before the call and it's 12 after the call. Yet the activity remains blank.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: The rest of my code (from the YT video, but adapted for my data class and firestore database):

```
// Tournament.kt
enum class Gender { Female, Male }
enum class Venue { Franchises, Évaux }
enum class Category { Womens, Mens, Mixed }
enum class Status { RegistrationOpen, RegistrationClosed, TournamentStarted, TournamentEnded, TournamentCanceled }
    
data class Team (
    var dateAdded: Date = Date(),
    var ranking: Int = 0,
    var players: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
)

data class Player (
    var id: String? = null,
    var userID: String = "",
    var dateAdded: Date = Date(),
    var gender: Gender = Gender.Female,
    var ranking: Int? = 0,
    var partner: String? = ""
)

data class Tournament (
    var season: String? = "2021",
    var date: Date? = Date(),
    var title: String? = "Tournoi de ",
    var venue: Venue? = Venue.Franchises,
    var category: Category? = Category.Mixed,
    var status: Status? = Status.RegistrationOpen,
    var maxNumberOfTeams: Int = 8,
    var includeInRankings: Boolean = true,
    var players: ArrayList<Player> = ArrayList(),
    var teams: ArrayList<Team> = ArrayList(),
)

// TournamentListAdapter.kt
class TournamentListAdapter (private var tournamentList: ArrayList<Tournament>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TournamentListAdapter.TournamentViewHolder>() {

    class TournamentViewHolder (view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder (view) {
        val titleTV: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tournamenTitle)
        val dateTV: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tournamenDate)
        val venueTV: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tournamenVenue)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() : Int {
        return tournamentList.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TournamentViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return TournamentViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TournamentViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val tournament = tournamentList[position]

        holder.titleTV.text = tournament.title
        holder.venueTV.text = tournament.venue.toString()
        holder.dateTV.text = tournament.date.toString()
    }
}

// MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var tournamentsList: ArrayList<Tournament>
    private lateinit var tournamentAdapter: TournamentListAdapter
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        tournamentsList = arrayListOf()
        tournamentAdapter = TournamentListAdapter(tournamentsList)

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recyclerView.adapter = tournamentAdapter

        EventChangeListener()    
    }

private fun EventChangeListener() {} // as defined above, option 1 and 2

// activity_main.xml
// not provided because, it works with Version 1, but not 2.
```

Comment: *When I add debug statements, I can confirm that tournamentsList.size is 0 before the call and it's 12 after the call.*, before and after which call? Are you referring to the second approach?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the approach that doesn't work. The first approach displays my list of items, so I didn't check the size of the array before/after.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you please edit your question and add those log statements, to see it more clearly?

Comment: Sure, tell me what you don't understand, and I'll explain.

Comment: I don't quite understand where in your code those statements produce that result. That's why I asked you to add them to your question.

Comment: I'll add the info you asked for, but I don't understand the relevance. I have a full project that works if a function is defined one way, but doesn't if the same function is defined a different way. So, it seems to be that the problem is the function itself, not the rest of the code..... this is a "test app" that I use to test a new thing/function before putting it my actual code. There are four files: MainActivity.kt, Tournament.kt (with more than , TournamentListAdapter.kt and activity_main.xml. I'll add above....

Comment: The second code should also work as well as the first one. That's why I don't understand in which place you get `I can confirm that tournamentsList.size is 0`.

Comment: I posted the relevant files on GitHub: https://github.com/reknoZ/FirestoreRecyclerViewEnum. You'd still need to attach to Firebase, though.

Comment: I still cannot see any log statements in your code that print `tournamentsList.size is 0`.

Comment: I only see this `Log.e ("Firestore error", error.message.toString())`.

Comment: Are you sure you have pushed the updates? I only see `Latest commit 273772a 2 hours ago`.

Comment: I'm talking about the code on this page with the Log.i lines. Update: done, added to GitHub, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235655/discussion-between-zonker-in-geneva-and-alex-mamo).

Comment: In both cases `Log.i ("BEFORE", tournamentsList.size.toString())` should print **0** and `Log.i ("AFTER ", tournamentsList.size.toString())` **12**. If it's not that way, I will definitely make a test.

Comment: That's exactly what they do. But, in one case, the Activity displays nothing, while in the other, the Activity displays my records. That's the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use `tournamentsList.addAll(snapshot!!.toObjects(Tournament::class.java) as ArrayList<Tournament>)`? Does it work this way?

Comment: I haven't, but I'll try it when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.